# Report Viewer Document Map issue with Office 2010 Word Export

Tags: asp.net, .net, reportviewer

I am struggling with Report Viewer (2012) Export Option. Every time I bind a column with Document map and I group that column for a collated data view, I see gibberish showing on my word doc export for that collated row. If I remove the document map from my Report View , I don't see the same happening. Whats happening here? Could any one help or feed in their ideas?

See image below:

[image]

Thanks,
Vaibhav.

Comment: This seems like a valid case; proven by MSDN's documentation. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283105.aspx#DocumentProperties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a valid case; proven by MSDN's documentation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283105.aspx#DocumentProperties